# How to get sensor value as variable

Tags: c#, variables, sensors

this is probably stupid question but I cannot handle it myself. I managed to get value of Light Sensor. I need to get this value as variable but I cannot access variable X. Could you help me out?

```
public class lightWakeup extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton imageButton;
    Intent navrat;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    TextView text;
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor sensor;
    float x;
    public float c;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_light_wakeup);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

                //zapnuti hudby
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hypnothis);
        mp.setVolume(50, 50);
        mp.start();

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(c));




        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
                navrat = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPage.class);
                startActivity(navrat);
            }
        });
    }
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(lightListener, sensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(lightListener);
    }

    public SensorEventListener lightListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int acc) { }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            x = event.values[0];
            text.setText((int)x);

        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the variable x the public modifier:

```
public float x;
```

By default, class variables without modifiers are set as "internal" in C#. You can see about variable modifiers at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx